# PurgeCSS whitelist patterns with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-purge

I am trying to preserve all TailwindCSS colour classes (i.e bg-green, bg-red, text-green, text-red) when it is processed via PurgeCSS. These colour classes are set in the CMS rather than code so we cannot search the code for them as they don't (all) exist here.

Therefore I want to use the [whitelisting feature](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-docs/blob/master/whitelisting.md) of PurgeCSS to retain all classes that beging with 'bg-' or 'text-'. However, the pattern I have below doesn't seem to be doing the trick? Any ideas how to tweak it?

```
whitelistPatterns: ['^bg\-', '^text\-'],
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue appears to be simply to use regexp, not a string.

```
whitelistPatterns: [/^bg-/, /^text-/], // Retain all classes starting with...
```

Answer (score 17):

If you run newer versions of tailwind: **whitelist** and **whitelistPatterns** merged into **safelist**. This info cost me a day of research.

```
purge: {
  options: {
    safelist: ["bg-red-50"],
  },
  // ... or even
  options: {
    safelist: [/^bg-/, /^text-/]
  },

}
```

Comment: I too wasted a day on this, but with react-bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

In TailwindCSS version 3.0.24 it is integrated a bit differently.

// Example tailwind.config.js (see my [config file](https://gist.github.com/JulianKasimir/d683ea15a83cd1e229c2fbcbe3637c47))

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'text-2xl',
    'text-3xl',
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Source: [Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations)

Comment: is there a way to adjust this pattern to include ALL colours, rather than specifying individually?

Comment: @dungey_140 this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73936087/12440036

Answer (score 3):

```
purge: {
  options: {
    safelist: ["whitelisted"],
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions), using something like this worked for a similar problem I had. The '+' works as wildcard.

```
module.exports = {
 // ...
 safelist: [
   {
      pattern: /bg-+/
   },
   {
     pattern: /text-+/
   },
 ],
 // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Im doing it based on [official suggestion](https://purgecss.com/whitelisting.html#specific-selectors) like this:

```
whitelistPatterns: [/\-blue\-/],
whitelistPatterns: [/\-pink\-/],
...etc
```

Selectors with ending or starting it does not fit your needs.
Think this one

```
.xl\:hover\:bg-pink-900:hover
```

or this one

```
.xl\:bg-cover
```