# Tailwind's background color is not being applied when added dynamically

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to set dynamic background colors using Tailwind.

However, the background color is not being applied to the div. I am confused because when I check the inspector, I can see that in the browser, the correct bg-${colors[index]} was applied to each div, but the color is not being rendered.

```
const colors = ['#7a5195', '#bc5090','#ef5675']

export default function App() {
  const names = ['Tyler', "Charles", 'Vince']
  let labels = {}

  names.forEach((name,index)=>{
    labels[name] = `bg-[${colors[index]}]`
  })

  return (
    <>
    {
      names.map((name)=>{
        return(
          <div className={`${labels[name]}`}>
        {name}
      </div>
          )
      })
    }
      
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use a whitelist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989191/purgecss-whitelist-patterns-with-tailwindcss

Answer (score 32, accepted):

in Tailwind you can't use dynamic class naming like `bg-${color}`.

This because when Tailwind compiles its CSS, it looks up over all of your code and checks if a class name matches.

If you want dynamic name classes you should write all the class name.

But for your specific use case, I would not use the JIT of Tailwind and instead use the `style` attribute and dynamically change the `backgroundColor` value.

It will use less CSS and also give you less headache.

Finally, this is my suggestion

```js
const colors = ['#7a5195', '#bc5090','#ef5675'];

export default function App() {
  const names = ['Tyler', "Charles", 'Vince']
  const labels = {};

  names.forEach((name, index) => {
    labels[name] = colors[index];
  });

  return (
    <>

    {
      names.map((name) => (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${labels[name]}` }}>
          {name}
        </div>
      )
    }
      
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: For the use of dynamic values in the classes, I made a hidden div at the root, with another div inside with all class names that the dynamic functions will result in. It's a bad format, but you will use all the features of Tailwind like sm:, lg:, and others. Using the style attribute you can't use mediaqueries and other rich features of the Tailwind.

Comment: @SandroSantos you should look into Tailwind's safelist to prevent adding that hidden div at the root : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Answer (score 2):

You can also add classes to your safelist in your tailwind config.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

// Create an array for all of the colors you want to use
const colorClasses = [
  '#7a5195', 
  '#bc5090',
  '#ef5675'
];

module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
    // Map over the labels and add them to the safelist
    safelist: [
      ...colorClasses.map((color) => `bg-${color}`)
    ],
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
}
```

This way you can use the colors that were included in the colorClasses array dynamically as they will not be purged.

Note: If you want to do bg-blue-500 for example, you'll need to include all of the color weights as part of the safelist (as well as add that color to the array).

```
...colorClasses.map((color) => `bg-${color}-500`)
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions to safe multiple classes at once. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Answer (score 1):

According to https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles:

```
<div class="bg-[#bada55] text-[22px] before:content-['Festivus']">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I successfully achieved the goal **strictly** with `"#bada55"` and no other options, such as red (`#FF0000`) and others.

Comment: If the primary variants were set before, on the "tailwind.config" file, does it work with bg-primary-[${colorNumber}]?

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Background Color in React Component with Tailwind CSS**

*I have a React component named VisitingCard where I want to dynamically set the background color based on a prop. Here's how I achieved it using Tailwind CSS:-*

```
const VisitingCard = (props) => {

// Destructuring props for ease of use 
const { colour, title, handle } = props;

// Object mapping color prop to Tailwind CSS background color classes  
const colorVariants = {
    green: 'bg-yellow-500',
    yellow: 'bg-red-400',
    blue: 'bg-blue-500'
  };

  return (
     <>  
       <div className={`w-40 h-20 border ${colorVariants[colour]}`}>
       <div>Title: {title}</div>
       <div>Handle: {handle}</div>
       </div>
     </>
  );
}

export default VisitingCard;
```

In this component, I use an object colorVariants to map color prop values to corresponding Tailwind CSS background color classes. This allows for dynamic styling based on the color prop passed to the component.

Now, when you use the VisitingCard component like this:-

```
<VisitingCard colour="green" title="John Doe" handle="@john_doe"/>
```

*It will render a div with a green background, and you can easily extend the `colorVariants` object with additional colors as needed.*

Answer (score -5):

Try this code

```
className={`bg-[${color}]`}
```

Comment: 2024 update: Despite the downvotes, this does work! See the documentation here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles. Make sure to use square brackets and a # before the color.