# how to change color in tailwind dynamically

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I getting  hex color code from database, I am trying to apply that color in div.

className={`bg-[${color}]`}

but the color is not applying, How can we change the color in tailwind dynamically from the color code getting from API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind's background color is not being applied when added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481680/tailwinds-background-color-is-not-being-applied-when-added-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t dynamically apply the color using tailwind. Because tailwind utility classes are generated at build time. But maybe you can achieve this quite easily with inline style like below.

`<div style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>Content here</div>`

I hope it helps.